# oracle practitionner only : UTL_ENCODE failing while sending pdf attached mail in 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

After lots of trial and error,I was able to send an email with UTL_SMPT. I the code below, in a previous version, I used a raw file and T_BLOB for `p_attach_file` and it sent a 32 K unreadable PDF as attachment. Not bad. But The PDF being greater than 32 K and also I want to be able to read it, I used the original version of the code. But it dos not work. It says UTL_ENCODE is failing in the FOR loop.

The error code is

[image]

Below is the full code of what I have done so far

**My code to read BLOB **

```
CREATE DIRECTORY PDF_DIR as 'c:\doc\';

create table tmpblob(x varchar2(200), y blob);

DECLARE
v_file_loc BFILE;
v_diagram_loc BLOB;
v_diagram_size INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_file_loc := BFILENAME('PDF_DIR','doc.pdf');
  v_diagram_size := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_file_loc);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pdf size: ' || v_diagram_size);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting Pdf Diagram Row');
  INSERT INTO tmpblob (x,y)
  VALUES (' ', EMPTY_BLOB )
  RETURNING y INTO v_diagram_loc;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Loading Content of PDF ');
  DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(v_diagram_loc, v_file_loc, v_diagram_size);
  COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OTHERS Exception ' || sqlerrm);
END; 

DECLARE
 -- l_name images.name%TYPE := 'site_logo.gif';
  l_blob tmpblob.y%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT y
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   tmpblob;

  send_mail(p_to          => 'root@mail.mycorp.com',
            p_from        => 'admin@mycompany.com',
            p_subject     => 'Test Message',
            p_text_msg    => 'This is a test message.',
            p_attach_name => 'doc.pdf',
            p_attach_mime => 'application/pdf',
            p_attach_blob => l_blob,
            p_smtp_host   => '192.168.50.1');
END;
```

**SEND_MAIL Procedure** : Source => [oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql#blob)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to          IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject     IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_text_msg    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_mime IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_blob IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_smtp_host   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port   IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
  l_step        PLS_INTEGER  := 12000; -- make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher than 24573
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  IF p_text_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_text_msg);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  IF p_attach_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime || '; name="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_attach_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_attach_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1))));
    END LOOP;

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your loop

```
FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_attach_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_attach_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1))));
END LOOP;
```

by this one:

```
OFFSET := 1;
amount := 48; -- must be a whole multiple of 3. I use 48 because it is common to place NEW_LINE each 64 characters.
LobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(p_attach_blob);
LOOP
   EXIT WHEN OFFSET > LobLen;
   DBMS_LOB.READ(p_attach_blob, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
   UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(BUFFER));
   OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
END LOOP;
```

A more advanced procedure you find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: Thank you. I added `amount number, OFFSET number, BUFFER blob` and the error does not appear anymore.... But the program is still sending a 0 K (null) pdf document as attachment.... Maybe `tmpblob` is containing an empty blob.... Don't know yet the reason... but thanks if I find it, and with your answer, I believe it will work fine.

Comment: Try `BUFFER RAW(48)` (size bigger/equal than `amount`).

Comment: I've tested it today... Actually I don't think it was adding `48` that made it work. The PL/SQL was loading an empty BLOB in the first place. I had not `dbms_lob.open` the file locator ....so it was not loading my file. But without your loop it would have not worked anyway... Thank you Wernfried